# why bond length of double bond is less than that of triple bond?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

why bond length of double bond is less than that of triple bond ? I came across this question many a times. I am confused because there is a sigma bond and two phi bond in triple bond and a sigma and phi bond in double bond. Hence bond length of both of them should be same. But it is not so.
Ex :- Carbon Carbon triple bond length is shorter  than C=C

Comment: Before you ask "why", ask "if".

Comment: perhaps you can give some examples to support your question?

Comment: Pretty sure phi bonds don't figure in $C-C$ or $C=C$ bonds...

Comment: You need to make up your mind whether $\ce{C#C}$ or $\ce{C=C}$ bonds are shorter.

Answer (score 1):

%s character of sp hybridised orbital is 50% and of sp2 it's 33%. More S-character means that the shared electron pair is closer to the carbon nucleus making it stronger and shorter.